# Jira as a test case execution tool

Tags: testing, jira, testcase, jira-zephyr

Is there a way to track test case exection & progress in Jira? I currently use the Test Management Workflow & provides me various phases like TestCaseReview, Pass, Fail, Invalid, ... 
But is there a way to assocaite the test status to a specific run.

For instance, I would like to execute 100 tests with a specfic filter for Release 1.0
Execute the same set of tests for Release 2.0 as well & track the status.

This was fairly simple in Zephyr (provided us options to create test cycles and add tests). But sadly, the plugin is not available for OnDemand version of Jira.

So, I am looking to accomplish the same functionality with a vanilla version of Jira

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe that what you want to do is possible in 'vanilla' JIRA.

The only possible way to do this in JIRA would be to create a 'swimlane' in JIRA for your release and then create individual JIRA tickets for each test (or given the large number of tests you have, small groups of tests) and then migrate the tickets through appropriate status values either as vertical swimlanes (or as sub-status) within a swim lane.

Sorry I can't suggest anything easier to manage.